# Download FTP using FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, ftp, download, directory, root

I use this code to download a file by FTP:

```
FtpWebRequest reqFTP; reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + IPServer + "/")); 
reqFTP.UseBinary = true; 
reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass); 
reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory; 
reqFTP.Proxy = null; 
reqFTP.KeepAlive = false; 
reqFTP.UsePassive = false; 
response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
```

---

But I have a problem. My credentials will make my user's home folder. I must go back to the root folder and select the specific folder to download the file.
how i specified in the Uri that i need go back?

I tried to use this /../ but is not working...

Little help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has nothing to do with your code ...

the ftp-server decides what's the ftp root folder.

for your credentials that seems to be that users home dir.

if you want to change that, check the ftp-server docs & config

Comment: Hi i found a solution. 
To navigate to the root folder is necessary this quote ipServer//..//..//Folder/Folder/....